# Parsing large RSS feeds using Rome, running out of memory

Tags: java, rss, rome

More specifically large XML webpages (RSS Feeds). I am using the excellent Rome library to parse them, but the page I am currently trying to get is really large and Java runs out of memory before getting the whole document.

How can I split up the webpage so that I can pass it to XMLReader? Should I just do it myself and pass the feeds in parts after adding my own XML to start and finish them?

Comment: In additon to how large the XML is, how are you going about processing it? What are you parsing the XML into? Suboptimal code can cause this just as easily as a large file can.

Comment: The feed in question is http://www.upstreamonline.com/rss2/companynews
according to http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/ its 346576 bytes.
 At the moment I just pass the URL into the ROME provided XmlReader class, which is then passed into (again ROMEs) SyndFeedInput() where the program then throws an exception at around the ~6000th line of the webpage. I'm running the program from cmd prompt as I want the program to be platform independent, from my IDE it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

First off learn to set the java command line options for Xms and Xmx to appropriate values, all the DOM based parsers each crap loads of memory. Second look at using a Pull Parser, it will not have to load the entire XML into a document before processing it.